# Heroku PostGres database update structure without deleting data

Tags: database, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, heroku

If I make database changes locally, and then use postgres with heroku, what does pushing the database actually do? Update schema, data, or both? There is no information on what actually happens when you push a database using the heroku toolbelt. I have a live production app that I don't want to overwrite data, but I have new unrelated tables and stuff that needs to be uploaded. Is there a good way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out you can run rake commands on your remote database like this:

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

Answer (score -1):

Just [connect to your database](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#pg-psql) from the command line:

```
heroku pg:psql
```

Comment: This doesn't do what I was asking about.